# Using ASP.NET label as SSRS report parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

- I have SSRS report with its own datasets coming straight from the database.  I have the report on ASP.NET application page.
- The application page header  has the username and user region details defined in the master page.
- Now, I want to read this region id label from the ASP.NET page and build my report accordingly.  Basically building dataset based on parameters coming from ASP.NET page.
- Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can send these as parameter to report....

```
ReportParameter rpt = new ReportParameter("name", "value");
```